# Netbeans - Whitespace

Tags: netbeans, ide

I have to use Netbeans which I never used before and there are 2 format settings driving me crazy :/

1) Dereferencing [i+1] is turned into [i + 1]. I hate these two whitespaces.

2) All my comments are directly put behind the code and all my tabs for ordering comments are lost.

I know I can set it somewhere in **Tools->Options->Editor->Formatting** but even after searching and googling (crazy word) I did not find this setting.

Answer (score 0):

For 1)

This is in Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting

The select Java as the language and "Spaces" as the Category.

It's in the section "Around Operators" and the one you are looking for is "Binary Operators". That however applies to *any* occurance of e.g. `+` (or `-` or other similar operators) not only between brackets. E.g. if that option is disable `i = x + y` is changed into `i = x+y`

I have no idea what you mean with 2)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. Is it possible to use this "binary operators" only in dereferencing brackets? and concerning the second aspect: I write a line of code, put a tab and write a comment. Thus, I can allign my comments over several lines. But by auto-formating the code, all tabs are lost and comments are written with only one whitespace behind the last code in the line.

Comment: Okay, the setting I was searching for was "keep extra spaces". This solves problem 2 :)